# Pegar os valores de todos os Options do select com jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-select, html-option

Tenho esse `<select>` que é gerado de forma dinâmica

```html
<select id="select_exemplo">
    <option id="exemplo">
    <option id="exemplo" value="10">teste 1 </option>
    <option id="exemplo" value="11">teste 2 </option>
    <option id="exemplo" value="18">teste 3</option>
    <option id="exemplo" value="25">teste 4</option>
</select>
```

Preciso pegar com o jQuery em forma de array todos os valores contidos no `value`, por exemplo `[10,11,18,25]`. Código jQuery:

```js
valor= jQuery('#select_exemplo').val()
```

Só que me retorna só o primeiro, no caso o `[10]`.

Comment: Do jeito que fez você está pegando o `val()` do **select** e não dos **options** e outra coisa errada que está fazendo é repetir **id´s**.

Comment: O HTML está mal formado. O option vazio tem que ter fechamento de tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Primeira coisa que fiz foi remover os id's "exemplo", já que em uma página html não se pode repetir um id.

Você pode fazer desta forma

```js
var valores = [];
$('#select_exemplo').find('option').each(function() {
  var valor = $(this).val();
  if(valor != "")
    valores.push(valor);
});
console.log(valores);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select_exemplo">
   <option>
   <option value="10">teste 1 </option>
   <option value="11">teste 2 </option>
   <option value="18">teste 3</option>
   <option value="25">teste 4</option>
</select>
```

Selecionei o "select" e usei o "find" para pegar todos os "option" e por fim fiz um `foreach` pegando cada `val` e jogando em um `array`.

E por fim fiz um if para não pega valores vazios.

Comment: dessa forma retornou assim:[
0:teste1 teste2 teste3 teste4 
1:10 
2:11
3:18 
4:25
]

Comment: Pode ser que na hora que você foi selecionar o elemento você utilizou a sua classe no lugar do seu id, e haja dois elementos com a mesma classe, desta forma ele vai pegar dois elementos, porem um teria que esta sem "value" e o outro com, você pode ver que no exemplo ele pega apenas os values.

Comment: entendi, teria como eu fazer também tirando a posição 0 do array?

Comment: Se você não quer pegar o primeiro "option" por esta vazio, o código que fiz já não vai pegar, já que fiz o "if(valor != "")...", mas se de qualquer forma você deseja remover o primeiro item do array basta fazer valores.splice(0, 1);

Answer (score 1):

Dei uma geral no seu HTML, que estava mal formado: não estava fechando o primeiro `<option/>`, que é vazio no seu caso. Caso não fosse, bastaria delegar-lhe um atributo `value` vazio, como exemplifiquei abaixo.

Outra coisa é que o `.val()` do `<select/>` só tem o valor do `<option>` selecionado. Para obter todos os `<option>`s, você precisa determinar isso no seu seletor jQuery: `$("#select_exemplo option")` e escrever um algoritmo que itere por cada `<option/>` e colete as informações desejadas.

```js
$(function () {
  var vals = [], val;
  $("#select_exemplo option").each(function () {
    (val = $(this).val()) && vals.push(val);
  });
  console.log('resposta: ' + vals.toString());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="select_exemplo">
  <option value=''>[Selecione]</option>
  <option value='10'>Maçã</option>
  <option value='11'>Banana</option>
  <option value='18'>Tomate</option>
  <option value='25'>Pêssego</option>
  <option value='52'>Melancia</option>
</select>
```

O `.each()` mostrado acima itera sobre os elementos selecionados com o seletor jQuery, como explicado [na documentação da API](https://api.jquery.com/each/),

> Description: Iterate over a jQuery object, executing a function for each matched element.

A palavra reservada `this` refere-se ao objeto jQuery iterado, quando usado dentro da função de *callback*,

> More importantly, the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so the keyword `this` refers to the element.

Portanto, ao se fazer `$(this).val()` dentro do bloco da função passada para `$("#select_exemplo option").each()` como *callback*, estamos obtendo o `.val()` de cada `<option>` contido no elemento (`<select>`) cujo `id` é `select_exemplo`,

```
$(function () { // Execute quando acabar de carregar toda a página.

  var vals = [], val; // Declaração das variáveis vals e val

  $("#select_exemplo option")/* < selecione os <option>s filhos 
                                  do item com id select_exemplo*/
                             .each(/* < itere */
                                   function () {
    (val = $(this)/* < pegue o <option> da iteração atual*/
                  .val() /* < pegue o value dele */
                        ) && /* < só continue executando à direita
                                  se não for string vazia */
                             vals.push(val) /* < enfileire val em vals */;
  });
  console.log('resposta: ' + vals.toString());/* < printe a resposta
                                                   separada por ","s */
});
```

Comment: pq usar `function (i, e)` sendo que as variáveis nunca são usadas no código?

Comment: Retirados `i` e `e`.